# How to use multiple .env files in Prisma?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, prisma, dotenv

I am working on a nestjs project using Prisma, and I want to use multiple .env files with Prisma. I follow the [guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/development-environment/environment-variables/using-multiple-env-files#setup-multiple-env-files) here. According to the guide, I add:

```
"migratetest:mysql": "dotenv -e .env.test -- npx prisma migrate dev",
"migratedev:mysql": "dotenv -e .env.development -- npx prisma migrate dev"
```

to my package.json. I run `migratetest:mysql` to load the .env.test file and do the migration. Then, I run `start: dev` to start the app. However, the Prisma said:

```
Error: error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
  -->  schema.prisma:10
   | 
 9 |   provider = "mysql"
10 |    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
   |
```

It seems that it can not find the .env file in my project (based on the guide, there is no .env file, it should change to .env.test and .env.development)

here is my .env.test:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:123456@localhost:3306/test
```

here is my  .env.development:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:123456@localhost:3306/dev
```

please help :)

Comment: share the content of .env files?

Comment: try prisma cli and run it with `prisma migrate dev` without npx

Comment: Hi, I update the .env

Comment: I tried following the guide you linked and I can't seem to replicate your issue. It works fine for me. Would it be possible to provide some kind of replication of the problem, perhaps on github?

Comment: Hi, Jakub's solution just save my day : )

Comment: Oh, that's great!

Answer (score 9):

You need to tell every script you have to use dotenv cli, so your `start:dev` should look like this:

```
"start:dev": "dotenv -e .env.development nest start --watch",
```

However, for me it's not starting the compilation in watch mode, I'm still trying to debug this. Any ideas?

EDIT: I posted this and 2 minutes later I was able to solve my issue :D The final version of the script should look like this:

```
"start:dev": "dotenv -e .env.development -- nest start --watch",
```

Reason for the need of two dashes being explained in [Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/development-environment/environment-variables/managing-env-files-and-setting-variables):

> Note: dotenv doesn't pass the flags to the Prisma command by default,
> this is why the command includes two dashes -- before prisma, making
> it possible to use flags like --force, --schema or --preview-feature.

Comment: It works for me!